# ¿ Cómo probar una clase File dentro de un método con Mockito?

Tags: archivo, junit, mockito

Estoy tratando de probar una clase utilitaria que genera un archivo.
Alguien me podría decir como mockear la clase File o algún otro enfoque para la prueba.

Al ejecutar la prueba me arroja el siguiente error:

```
ERROR:: \tmp\ReporteTest.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Mi clase utilitaria es esta:

```
public class UtilReportes{
public static ResultDTO generaArchivo(ResultDTO dto, List<ResultDTO> lista){
    ResultDTO data= new ResultDTO();
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        String fileName = "/tmp/ReporteTest.txt";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.exists()) {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            //mas lógica aqui


    } else {
    //algo mas por aqui 
    }

    }catch (IOException | java.io.IOException e) {

    e.getMessage();
    }finally{
        try {
            if(bw != null){ bw.close(); }

        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
             e.getMessage();
        }
    }       
    return data;

}}
```

Mi clase de test es algo así:

```
public class UtilReportesTest { 
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
@Before
public void setUp() {   
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testArchivo() {
    ResultDTO dto = new ResultDTO();


     List<ResultDTO> lista = new ArrayList<>();
     ResultDTO res = UtilReportes.generaArchivo(dto, lista);
        File fileTest = temporaryFolder.newFolder("/tmp/ReporteTest.txt");
        //la idea es que cuando se alcance la linea de new File("/tmp/ReporteTest.txt")
        //me regrese el archivo creado con temporaryFolder
        Mockito.when("new File.clas").thenReturn(fileTest);
    assertNotNull(fileTest);
     assertNotNull(res);

}
}
```

NOTA: No puedo utilizar PowerMock para realizar la prueba, debido a una restricción en las dependencias (políticas de la empresa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente solucioné mi prueba, fue necesario añadir algunos metodos a la clase de utileria:

```
public class UtilReportes {

public String validarRuta(String path) {
    if (path == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return path;
}

public File getFile(String path) {
    return new File(path);
}

public FileWriter getFileWriter(File file) throws java.io.IOException {
    return new FileWriter(file);
}

public BufferedWriter getBufferedWriter(FileWriter fileWriter) {
    return new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
}}
```

mi clase de test contiene lo siguiente:

```
public class UtilReportesTest {
@Mock
File mockFile;

@Mock
FileWriter mockFileWriter;

@Mock
BufferedWriter mockBufferedWriter;

private UtilReportes spyReportes = spy(new UtilReportes());

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

}

@Test
public void testWithFile() throws IOException {
    doReturn("ReporteTest.txt").when(spyReportes).validarRuta("/tmp/ReporteEspecial.txt");

    List<ResultDTO> lista = null;
    ResultDTO dto = new ResultDTO();

    doReturn(mockFile).when(spyReportes).getFile("ReporteTest.txt");

    doReturn(mockFileWriter).when(spyReportes).getFileWriter(mockFile);

    doReturn(mockBufferedWriter).when(spyReportes).getBufferedWriter(mockFileWriter);

    assertNotNull(spyReportes.generaArchivo(dto, lista, null));
}}
```

Estos recursos fueron muy utiles:
[Mock a constructor with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364406/mock-a-constructor-with-parameter])
[Wiki Mockito en google](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mockito/wikis/MockingObjectCreation.wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Mockerar un constructor de una clase se hace asi:

```
Mockito.when(new File(any(String.class).thenReturn(fileTest)));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alexmaister, pero encontré que no se puede hacer directamente. En este enlace lo explican, dice que se puede emular el comportamiento a través de un metodo [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364406/mock-a-constructor-with-parameter]